# sqlite cursorindexoutofbound exception

Tags: android, sqlite

> in my android application i used the following function to retrieve the column from the table..the table contains value but it has an exception.

```
 public String[] getactivelist(){
        Log.v("ppp","getactivelist");
        String[] actname=new String[50];
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.v("ppp","dbcrtd");
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM activelist ORDER BY time ASC", null);
        Log.v("ppp","aftrcurser");
        int i=0;
        Log.v("ppp crsr",cursor.getString(0));
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                actname[i]=cursor.getString(0);
                Log.v("ppp crsr",cursor.getString(0));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return actname;
    }
```

the log cat shows the following error

```
04-04 01:19:41.170    2581-2601/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker V/ppp﹕ tryandroid.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In your line

```
Log.v("ppp crsr", cursor.getString(0));
```

You try to get a string from the cursor. If there aren't any lines, it should throw the error observed.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the following line...

```
Log.v("ppp crsr",cursor.getString(0));
```

...before you have moved the position of your `Cursor` using...

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
```

By default, the position of a `Cursor` is initially set to be -1 which is *before* the first valid position as the first position which contains data is position 0.

Simply remove that line (the one before the `if(...)`) and you should be good to go.

On another note, in your `do...while` loop you are using...

```
actname[i]=cursor.getString(0);
```

...but you never increment `i`. Consequentially you will only ever modify `actname[0]` regardless of how many results are returned to the `Cursor`.